# Google Cloud connecting first time through ftp but in few seconds reverting to permission denied on write (the file is going blank on this case)

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am connecting to my project files through FileZilla (hosted in Google Clouds). It was working fine till yesterday. Starting yesterday I am getting issues:

When I restart the compute engine FileZilla is working for fine few seconds. Then it reverts back to permission issue or showing Failed while saving files.

I checked with permissions and everything looks fine. My project files is inside 'var/www/html'

Filezilla log:

```
Status: Connected to {cloud_ip_here} 
Status: Starting download of /var/www/html/{app_name}/api/application/controllers/Test.php 
Status: File transfer successful, transferred 1,920 bytes in 1 second 
Status: Starting upload of C:\Users{my_pc_name}\AppData\Local\Temp\fz3temp-2\Test.php 
Command: put "C:\Users{my_pc_name}\AppData\Local\Temp\fz3temp-2\Test.php" "Test.php" 
Error: /var/www/html/{app_name}/api/application/controllers/Test.php: open for write: permission denied 
Error: File transfer failed
```

Answer (score 0):

Weirdly, the issue was server ran out of space and that's the reason it was showing permission denied. It has nothing to do with permissions. To check space in ssh of Compute Engine instance go for "df" command.